# How to delete static file (css) from shared components repository in Oracle ApEx

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have uploaded a css file, and now I want to update it's code. So when I try to upload it again, I get an error that the file exists. I am trying to delete the file but I can't find anywhere this option!

I am using Application Express 4.2.2.00.11

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using version 4.2.0

Starting on the shared components page:

[image]

Select the Cascading Style Sheets link:

[image]

Select the CSS file that is of interest and you will be shown a screen with the option to delete the file:

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! When I chose as a view option the "view report", I couldn't see the code of the file because when clicking on it, it started downloading it. The trick was to turn on the icons view.